# How can I set a variable from navigator to global to be available in all pages in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I sent this data to a page, but I can't send it through navigation again since I am navigating through `bottomnavigationbar`.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ContactPage(
            username: username.text,
            userId: userId,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

then I click on the `bottomnavigationbar` to go to another page, it's null that way.... and I can't save it to navigation... I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Is `username` a `TextEditingController`?

Comment: nope, it was gotten from the first page.

Answer (score 0):

create the list of widget like this

```
List<Widget> _children() => [
HomePageScreen(name: username.text),
SettingScreen(),
```

];

to use this list follow this code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{

final List<Widget> children = _children( );

return Scaffold
(
    
    body: children[currentIndex],
    
)
```

}

Comment: i dont understand this

Comment: To make the variable global you can directly declare that variable in main class after the import statement, then that variable can be used in any of the class even you can change the value of it,

Sorry for previous solution i thought you want to pass it in the bottomnavigaiton tab